# Is there a way for a SOLR plugin to get a callback when SOLRCloud Has Successfully Elected A Master

Tags: plugins, solr, solrcloud

We have a SOLR plugin (a special RequestHandler for our purposes) that gets two callbacks from SOLR when starting up, an RequestHandler.init method, and a SolrCoreAware.inform(SolrCore core) method. In the SolrCoreAware.inform method, we start a Kafka consumer.

The problem is that sometimes the plugin gets a Kafka message to process (which it just forwards to another SOLR update handler to index) before SolrCloud has finished starting up. In that case Solr throws an exception after waiting for a while. Is there a way to get a callback into my plugin of some sort only when the SolrCloud has finished starting up, so that I can delay starting the Kafka consumer until then? Of course I could have some hacky way of introducing a fixed time based delay but was hoping the system could tell me that its ok to initialize.

Thanks.

P.S.:

The exception I get is the following:

Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No registered leader was found after waiting for 4000ms , collection: taxonomy slice: shard1
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.getLeaderRetry(ZkStateReader.java:676)
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.getLeaderRetry(ZkStateReader.java:662)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.setupRequest(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:361)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.setupRequest(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:312)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:662)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader$1.handle(JsonLoader.java:227)
        at org.apache.solr.common.util.JsonRecordReader$Node.handleObjectStart(JsonRecordReader.java:364)
        at org.apache.solr.common.util.JsonRecordReader$Node.parse(JsonRecordReader.java:289)
        at org.apache.solr.common.util.JsonRecordReader$Node.access$200(JsonRecordReader.java:154)
        at org.apache.solr.common.util.JsonRecordReader.streamRecords(JsonRecordReader.java:138)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.handleSplitMode(JsonLoader.java:205)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:122)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:110)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:73)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:103)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1984)
        at com.aol.dmp.solr.kafka.SolrKafkaHandler.processDoc(SolrKafkaHandler.java:407)

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody has answered that, I'll have a go.

Looking at the SolrCloud lifecycle, I think you can achieve that with the newSearcher-callback of SolrEventListener. It gets notified after the initial core loading and after each commit when a new searcher has been instantiated.

```
public void newSearcher(SolrIndexSearcher newSearcher, SolrIndexSearcher currentSearcher) {
    if (currentSearcher == null) {
        //First searcher after the core has loaded.
    } else {
        //New searcher after commit.
    }
}
```

You can register the listener inside the inform-Callback:

```
core.registerFirstSearcherListener(whatEverSolrEventListenerSeemsFit);
```

Comment: Seems very promising. I'll give it a try later, but since I'm relaxing on a beach vacation, I'll up vote it in advance :-) if nothing else it gives an avenue to explore and no one else had any suggestions

Comment: Glad I could (possibly) help. Have a nice vacation.